# Discussion:Can Angular generate template automatically?

Tags: angular

if I have ts file like this:

```
class demo {
  onNgInit(){
    TextField()
  }
}
```

is there any way to generate a template file like this?

```
<input />
```

I really like SwiftUI Declarative programming，can angular like SwiftUI？

or support me an explorable way to implement it？

thank you buddy！thanks for your help ：）

Comment: Can you share few links for the code style you are trying to get? Here are some other ways to generate code: 1. In Angular we can write our own schematics to generate component the way we want. 2. In VS Code, you can add snippets. Both these could help you to accelerate the development.

Comment: @NikhilWalvekar thank you for your reply, I'm sorry I don't have any link because it's just an idea in my brain. Maybe I should paste some fake codes here :) thanks againnn!